# Characterset problem while inserting into mysql database from java application

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding

I have written a application that parses the html code of some web pages. My problem is with inserting that data into my mysq database. So for example i want to insert ľščťžýáíé and when i look into the table i get ?š??žýáíé.

I guess the problem could be that the html pages i'm downloading are encoded in cp1250. but the database is utf8.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"cp1250"));
```

and this is how i download the data.

Do you have some ideas how to fix this problem? Because i allready ran out.

Edit: oh and when i write the data out to the console (with System.out, i know i shouldn't use it... :) ) then every character is showing up correctly.

Comment: how do you look into the table? Make sure that the program you use to see what's in the db has the charset set to utf-8

Comment: i use phpmyadmin, and i'm pretty sure it supports utf8, but i have a hunch there's some error while inserting... like my java application not converting those characters properly or somehow the connection is misconfigured, and i can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out what works.

As i'm connecting to via JDBC to MySQL i used the following connection string

```
conString = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+database+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
```

And this did the trick. I had to force JDBC to use utf8 for the connection using `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`

Answer (score 0):

issue a `set names CP1251;` just after your connect to mysql and before any inserts